# Can anyone tell me why I'm still getting an INVALID_CLIENT message? Spotipy on mac

Tags: python, localhost, spotify, spotipy

I am trying to build a Spotify player with python and spotipy. I keep getting a message that says INVALID_CLIENT. The client id is entered properly along with the secret and the username

```
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials

cid ="xx" 
secret = "xx"
username = "xx"

client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=cid, client_secret=secret) 
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)

scope = 'user-library-read playlist-read-private'
token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username,scope,client_id='http://localhost:8888/callback/',client_secret='http://localhost:8888/callback/',redirect_uri='http://localhost:8888/callback/')

if token:
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
else:
    print("Can't get token for", username)
cache_token = token.get_access_token()

sp = spotipy.Spotify(cache_token)
currentfaves = sp.current_user_top_tracks(limit=20, offset=0, time_range='medium_term')

print(currentfaves)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using both the Client Credentials and Authorization Code Flow. To get user's top tracks, you need to use Authorization Code Flow.

You should remove the client credentials lines, then make sure the `util.prompt_for_user_token` call is configured properly. In your code, you have all parameters set to your redirect URI, which is giving you the Invalid Client error. Seems like you're following the Spotipy documentation, which is incorrect for this call. I'll try to make a PR.

Your code should look like this:

```
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util

cid ="xx" 
secret = "xx"
username = "xx"

scope = 'user-library-read playlist-read-private'
token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username,scope,client_id=cid,client_secret=secret,redirect_uri='http://localhost:8888/callback/')

if token:
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
else:
    print("Can't get token for", username)
cache_token = token.get_access_token()

sp = spotipy.Spotify(cache_token)
currentfaves = sp.current_user_top_tracks(limit=20, offset=0, time_range='medium_term')

print(currentfaves)
```

Comment: I did this but I still get this error in Chrome: This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.
Search Google for localhost 8888 callback
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Yes, that's fine. That's just because you're not actually running a server on localhost.

Check the terminal where you're running your python script - it should prompt you for the URL you're redirected to. Grab the full URL from the address bar in Chrome and paste it there.